# Use CSS to Change Styles for Images that are Less Than 50px

Tags: css, image, css-selectors

I am stylizing online documentation using CSS. The kicker is that I do not have access to the HTML because it is using third-party software (Confluence). Therefore, I cannot make up new classes and I cannot add any scripts to the HTML.

The issue is this: We have documentation where images of buttons are included in the text of a step. Here is an example:

3. In the popup box, enter related comments and click [image of Okay button] to commit your changes.

[image of popup box that includes Okay button]

4. The page is updated with the changes.

Unfortunately, the same class that controls the image embedded within the step controls the image below the step. This class is set with margins so that the image between the steps has space. All the images that are within the sentence for the step have a height less than 30px. Is there a way to say "for all images with this class that have a height less than 30px, margin:0" - is there a way to do this?

Comment: No .... but what you can do is set a selector for ""All images inside a sentence", you just need to evaluate the parent sentence for example : `p.sentence > img`

Comment: I can't make up a "sentence" class because I am using a third-party product.

Comment: It's just an example, you just need to inspect the parent element and see what you can use, the tag name, the classname, and id of some greater parent ... make an specific route